# loading data to hashmap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String,ArrayList<ClassOb>>>>

Tags: java

I am trying to load data to hash map of hash map and i keep getting null pointer and not sure if i am doing the right thing.

I want my hash map to be based on three keys SalesAreaCode, year and product. I want to store the rest in arraylist. I want to pass sales area code , year and product and list all product such as customer, quantity , price related to these three keys:
I really need help or someone to point me to the right direction. Any help will be appreciated!! Alan

Code:

```
 public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Sales>>>> getSalesDetails(Connection con)
{
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Sales>>>>> hmpSales =
        new  HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Sales>>>>>();
        Sales s;
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<Sales>> hmpSalProd = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Sales>>();
        HashMap<String,HashMap<String,ArrayList<Sales>>> hmpSalYear = 
        new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Sales>>>();    

       try
       {
             pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs=pst.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next())
       {
                  s=new Sales();

                  if(!(hmpSalProd.containskey(rs.getString("product"))))
                  {
                       s.setSalesCode(rs.getString("sacd"));
                       s.setCustomerCode(rs.getString("custcd"));
                       s.setYear(rs.getInt("year"));
                       s.setProduct(rs.getString("product"));
                       s.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
                       s.setQty(rs.getInt("qty"));
                       hmpSalProd.put(rs.getString("product"),
                       new ArrayList<Sales>(Arrays.asList(s)));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      s.setSalesCode(rs.getString("sacd"));
                      s.setCustomerCode(rs.getString("custcd"));
                      s.setYear(rs.getInt("year"));
                      s.setProduct(rs.getString("product"));
                      s.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
                      s.setQty(rs.getInt("qty"));
                      hmpSalProd.get(rs.getString("product")).add(s);
                  }
                  if(!(hmpSalYear.containsKey(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("year")))))
                  {
                      hmpSalYear.put(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("year")),hmpSalProd);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      hmpSalYear.get(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("year"))).
                      get(rs.getString("product")).add(s);
                  }

                  if(!(hmpSalArea.containsKey(rs.getString("sacd"))))
                  {
                     hmpSales.put(rs.getString("sacd"),hmpSalYear);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      hmpSales.get(rs.getString("sacd")).
                      get(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("year"))).
                      get(rs.getString("product")).add(s);
                  }

          }
          pst.close();
          rs.close();
     }
     catch(SQLException se)
     {
           System.out.println("error loading: " + se.getMessage());
     }
     return hmpSales;

}
```

Comment: Write some POJOs representing your data instead of using a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Sales>>>>`

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Where do you get an NPE?

Comment: new ArrayList<Sales>(Arrays.asList(s))); s is not an array...

Comment: Your code is really awful, please reindent it and correct your compilation errors.

Comment: You could also use google collections Multimap, it would make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define 2 classes :

- a `SalesKey` class storing the SalesAreaCode, year and product, overriding equals and hashCode, non alterable (no way to change a value once created)
- a `SalesData` class storing the data to be mapped to the sale key (including the SalesAreaCode, year and product).

Then you will be able to use a `Map<SalesKey, SalesData>`. That is easier to understand, thus easier to implement what you want to achieve.